# TortoiseSVN Command Line Merge in Windows

Tags: powershell, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to get TortoiseSVN to preform a test merge from power shell / command line.

The command I'm using in powershell is:

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:merge --dry-run --force /fromurl:$pullurl /path:$path
```

This will give the window that pops up the proper "Url to merge from" , but the "Working copy" does not point to the branch (instead it points to my trunk folder.).

What are the parameters for the /command:merge instruction?

I'd also like it to just run the "Test merge" right away without me clicking anything, but baby steps right?

Comment: If you want to automate anyway, don't bother trying to automate the GUI. Just run `svn merge` directly.

Comment: svn merge complains about the server being too old.  this at least pops up the merge window

Comment: Update the server first, then? Why would you believe that GUI and CLI of the same program would behave in different ways?

Comment: ? Have you worked in corporate IT? - getting them to update anything at more than a snails pace is an accomplishment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Szanowny panie, if you want to automate anyway - do not hesitate to read [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html). *Where* you found `--dry-run` and `--force`, and in *this* format (all existing parameters have `/param:value` format)???

For calling ToertoiseProc inside of WC like this

`>TortoiseProc.exe /command:merge /fromurl:http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/branche-francaise/ /path:.`

I get dialogue with correctly pre-filled data

[image: Merge Window]

"Force" and "Test merge" are handwork (checkbox and button) on **next** step, **not automated**

Comment: the only thing I was missing was cd (cmd.exe) or set-location (powershell) to the directory the folder is in, then "."  Spasiba!  It would be great if it launced directly into the test merge, but as a daily task that runs once a day, this should be good enough.

Comment: @AlexanderMatusiak - you can launch from any dir, just change `/path:.` in command to `/path:"full\path to directory\with WC\and spaces in name".`